# GroovyClassLoader not found plugin config file

Tags: grails, gradle, build.gradle, grails-plugin, grails3

I create a gradle application project, and a gradle plugin project.

When I run the plugin project, the class loader manages to find the config file.
but when I run the application project, It throws:
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testutilsConfig"
TestutilsGrailsPlugin.groovy:

```
void doWithApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Implement post initialization spring config (optional)
    GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader())
    ConfigObject config
    try {
        config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(classLoader.loadClass('testutilsConfig'))
        ApplicationContextHolder.config.merge(config)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println("Cannot load config for testutilsConfig")
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the ivy dependency. It's not added by default because it's declared as non-transitive. Ivy is the library which manages the dependencies loaded by @Grab

Comment: Ivy is not used by Grails 3 or Gradle, and the question says nothing about @Grab